# A review keeps being suggested to me

Tags: bug, review

This is the sixth time in the past 3 hours I am seeing this review being suggested to me, as shown in this picture.

[image]

However, I have [reviewed it a couple hours ago](https://ell.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/75276). It keeps coming back after a few minutes. Is it a bug?

Comment: It looks like the review completed with a third "reject" vote about half an hour after you posted here. It does seem odd that it would keep showing you one you had already voted on.

Comment: If you choose to skip it, it can show up again.

Answer (score 3):

The one shown on the screenshot is a *different* review, suggesting the same edit.

[#75276](https://ell.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/75276) is the one you have reviewed, and has been rejected. However, [#75277](https://ell.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/75277) suggested the same edit, and it's shown to you (and everyone else) when accessing the review queue again.

Based on the behavior, looks like someone was deliberately trying to vandalize the post...

Comment: It was my guess too. Now I am not so sure this is the case. I repeated my review multiple times, but after I rejected the edit suggestion each time, it still came back to my review queue. I even tried to reject it under different reasons, but that didn't prevent it from showing up again. And the weird thing is, only my first vote appeared in my review history. The rest didn't leave a trace.